# Why is the definition of a closure like this?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is from the Numerical Optimization's third lecture at [this point](https://youtu.be/55wN7ajTyIE?list=PL6EA0722B99332589&t=2479).

Here is a reprint.

> Let $S$ be subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $x$ which is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to the closure of $S$, denoted $\operatorname{cl}(S)$, if for each $e > 0$, $S \cap B[x,e] \neq\varnothing$.
>
> Example: Let $S = (1,2] \cup [3,4)$. Then $\operatorname{cl}(S) = [1,2] \cup [3,4]$

I am having difficulty understanding why this definition means what the examples show. Wouldn't the above hold true for essentially every $x$ as long as $e > 0$, and that would include points far away from the boundary of $S$?

Comment: The key is the 'for each' part. Consider $x=5$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$ then cleary the ball $B[5, 01.]$ does not contain any points from $S$.

Comment: But if e = 0.1 wouldn't S /\ B[x,e] hold true for every x in [4,4.1)?

Comment: Ah, I get it. If x=4.2, then it would not hold for e in (0,2].

Comment: I see what you meant. I made a mental error in not thinking about the lower part of e, which is strange as I did not make the mistake of mentally looping over e rather that x first. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly. The point if these arguments is fixing $x$ and letting $\epsilon$ vary.